# CodenameOne calander event for next/previous month arrow

Tags: codenameone

How can I customize the events on the left/previous and right/next buttons in a Calender component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to the `com.codename1.ui.Calendar`. You can't customize the key events but you can track selection changes which might be enough using the `addDataChangeListener` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,anyhow we have managed to implement the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Codename One **doesn't** have a Calender Component with previous and next button (or maybe i've missed it !). 
If it's a **native** component, you have to implement a NativeInterface to interact with your calendar